# How to find the temperature for when Kc = 1

Tags: equilibrium, enthalpy, free-energy

The formulas I can use are $\Delta$G = H - T$\Delta$S, and $\Delta$G = $\Delta$G(s.t.d) + RTlnK

I understand that when Kc is 1, the reaction is barely spontaneous and thus I can use the first formula for when $\Delta$G = 0 to find T. However, I have trouble understanding why the second formula can't be used here, or if it can, I don't know how exactly.

Overall, with my current understanding of the formulas, I am running into contradictions whenever trying to calculate something.

If someone can also explain to me as to how the first equation and second equation relate to each other, and provide a comprehensive explanation of gibbs free energy at equilibrium, it would be very helpful.

Comment: For better site experience, you may find useful these links:
 [notation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [formulas/expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) ( not to be applied to titles ) and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: What do you call $\pu{\Delta G(s.t.d)}$ ?

Comment: Standard Gibbs free energy change.

Comment: It is better to write `$\Delta G°$` or `$\Delta G^{\circ}$`   to be displayed as $\Delta G^{\circ}$  // $\Delta G^{\circ}= -RT\ln{K}$